# ora 00920 неверный реляционный оператор

Tags: sql

```
select * 
    from empc_files_b_transactions b,bf_globuz_acc_tr_all t 
     where t.terminal_id  LEFT JOIN b.term_nr
     and (b.e_date between to_date('01.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') and  to_date('31.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

Comment: The `WHERE` needs to go after the FROM and JOIN clauses

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select * 
    from empc_files_b_transactions b
LEFT JOIN bf_globuz_acc_tr_all t
on (t.terminal_id = b.term_nr)
where b.e_date between to_date('01.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') 
and  to_date('31.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy');
```